# BadMethodCallException when using with() in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

I get the following error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1999: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Client()
```

when using Laravel 5 eager loading with()

```
$products = Product::with(['Client'])->get();
```

A client can have many products. A product belongs to one client.

Product model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {

/**
 * Client who has this product.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}
```

Client model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model {

/**
 * Appointment that this client has.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasMany
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Am I missing a relationship? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `with()` call should use the name of the relationship function, `clients`, not the name of the related class, `Client`. I believe it may also be case-sensitive.

```
$products = Product::with('clients')->get();
```

Comment: Got it! It works, but when I return Response::json($products);  I get "clients":null , but I know this client exists

Comment: Clients would be a property of each individual product, not its own array in the response.

Comment: Hm ok, I thought I was going to be able to join every product with its client, and display the client info for each listed product in my view. Not sure what should be the query / return syntax then.

Comment: In my Laravel install, `App\Foo::with('bar')->get()->toJson();` works fine. It'll give you an array of products. Each product will have its attached clients as a property. If you want a separate list of clients, you'll need to fetch it.